# How do I open a .rar file on IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x

There is a treasurehunt.rar file I have never worked with them before and cant find anything online, how do I open it on python IDLE?

Comment: Within the .rar file there is a python code which I want to use but I need to extract it from the .rar file

Comment: Google for *extract rar on <insert your operating system name>*

Comment: when i download winrar what then?

Comment: Open the .rar file and extract the python file then open it in the IDE.  .rar is an archive like .zip

Answer (score 0):

There is a rarfile library for Python.

https://rarfile.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html